# Angular.js: Input date shows date -1 day

Tags: angularjs, date

I have a form with `<input type="date">`.

When I bind data in this input, it shows me the date -1 day.

The HTML:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <label>Fecha Nacimiento </label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fnac" name="fnac" ng-model="unapersona.fnac">
</div>
```

The Controller:

```
$scope.cargarpersona = function(id) {
    $http.get("modelos/personas_json.php?id="+id)
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.unapersona = eval(data);
        //... Other data
        $scope.unapersona.fnac = new Date($scope.unapersona[0]["fnac"]);
        //... Other data
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
}
```

[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvCXd.png)

Comment: what date format does $scope.unapersona[0]["fnac"] return?

Comment: What data comes back from your ajax call?

Comment: return the JSON format '2016-03-17'. In list view show date correctly, when I save changes, save correctly (the date of <input>+1).

Comment: try `new Date($scope.unapersona[0]["fnac"] + " UTC")`

Comment: Sorry @FabioG, Don't work...

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zvCXd.png

Answer (score 9):

Solved!!
Just I put the **ng-model-options = "{timezone 'UTC'}** into the input date

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="fnac" name="fnac" ng-model="unapersona.fnac" ng-model-options="{timezone:'UTC'}">
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Thanks for yours answers and time!

Comment: I just stumbled on this solution myself, glad you found it also :)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running into timezone problems. Consider the following Code ([Plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/jWcPT8yHLjtkqhvvR3wC?p=preview))

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.aDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 02, 17, 0, 0, 0));
  $scope.aSecondDate = new Date(2016, 02, 17, 0, 0, 0);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h4>UTC Date</h4>
    <p>{{aDate}}</p>
    <h4>Local Date</h4>
    <p>{{aSecondDate}}</p>
  </body>
```

**Output (on a CET browser):**

```
UTC Date

"2016-03-17T00:00:00.000Z"

Local Date

"2016-03-16T23:00:00.000Z"
```

In the first case the date is set with `UTC` as the timezone.

In the second case, the date is set with the `local` timezone (your browser's settings), and then converted to `UTC` (which at the moment differs by 1h from `CET`), and because that puts the date over midnight, this is a different day.

Comment: Sorry... with the Date.UTC function, don't show any date in <input>.
I don't think it Timezone problems, because in the list view displays the correct date

Comment: How did you try the code? Can you provide the changed code? And can you provide your list view in your original question also? Which timezone are you in?

Comment: $scope.unapersona.fnac = new Date(Date.UTC($scope.unapersona[0]["fnac"]));

Comment: This won't work, Date.UTC expects multiple arguments: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Comment: I tried this, but does not show the date in the input:

var date = new Date($scope.unapersona[0]["fnac"]);
            $scope.unapersona.fnac = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth() + 1),date.getDate());

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `date` input type expects `/` instead of `-`, havent tested but hope it works:

```
   .success(function(data) {
        $scope.unapersona = eval(data);

        var from_data = $scope.unapersona[0]["fnac"];
        var date_replace = from_data.replace(/-/g, '/');

        var date = new Date(date_replace );
        $scope.unapersona.fnac = ((date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +  // JS months are 0 indexed and days are 1 indexed
                                   date.getDate() + '/' +                                                                                  
                                   date.getFullYear());
        })
```

Comment: what date does it return?  for example if $scope.unapersona[0]["fnac"] was 2016-03-17?

Comment: and what do you see in the html input type= date ?

Comment: ok I updated my answer, seems to be that with - istead of / there is some kind of js bug, tested answer in console and seems to work fine