# Previous day inserted instead of current date in Mysql

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc

i have a problem when inserting date. So instead of inserting the current date when i click on the calendar, it inserts the previous day, today is 28/12 it inserts 27/12. My time zone UTC+1. Below my code

My application.properties and my class are below.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestionChequeApp?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Paris
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= ****
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port = 8081

@Entity
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class Cheque {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idCheque;
    private Long numCheque;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

 //...
```

When i execute SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone; it gives me SYSTEM and SYSTEM for both. Have you any idea for this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Can we see the calendar code?

Comment: Hi Okeme, I mean Calendar of html, input type date, not java calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it's from date picker not backend code. I just added ng-model-options = "{timezone 'UTC'} to my input type date. I found it throught this link. 
[Angular.js: Input date shows date -1 day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063131/angular-js-input-date-shows-date-1-day)